# excluding databases from mysqldump under windows without external tools

Tags: vbscript, batch-file, mysql

As subject I'd like to know if it's possible to use mysqldump excluding some databases under windows.
I've already googled and I've found this:

http://datacharmer.blogspot.com/2010/12/excluding-databases-from-mysqldump.html

but I'm looking for a solution under windows that doesn't require external tool like powershell,gnuwin32 and so on. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is my final script. It obviously requires odbc driver.

```
set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
user = "my_user"
password = "my_password"
mysqlPath = "C:\mysql_path\bin\mysqldump.exe"
bkDate = DatePart("yyyy",Date) _
         & Right("0" & DatePart("m",Date), 2) _
         & Right("0" & DatePart("d",Date), 2)
dumpPath = "c:\my_path\dump_" & bkDate & ".txt"
strDbList = ""
cn.connectionString = "Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};Server=localhost;User="&user&";Password="&password&";"
cn.open
rs.open "select schema_name from information_schema.schemata where schema_name not in('db1','db2','.....') order by schema_name", cn, 3
rs.MoveFirst
while not rs.eof
    strDbList = strDbList & rs(0) & " "
    rs.movenext
wend
oshell.run "cmd /k " & mysqlPath & " -u" & user & " -p" & password & " --database " & strDbList & "> " & chr(34) & dumpPath & chr(34),0    
cn.close
set oShell = nothing                                                          
set rs = nothing
```

Hope that it helps someone else.

Answer (score 1):

You could easily write a short piece of code to do the correct output selection in your language of your choice.